# How to understand the symbolic integral in a result returned by DSolve?

Tags: differential-equations, special-functions

I am trying to solve an ODE like
$$\frac{dF}{dx}=\frac{a}{\ln^3 x+[c+d(ax+b)][2\ln x+c+d(ax+b)]\ln x},$$
where $a,b,c,d$ are constants. I guess it could contain a special function, say, the logarithmic integral function
$$li z=\int_0^z \frac{dt}{\ln t}$$

Using the following simple code:

```
DSolve[
  F'[x] == 
    a/((Log[x])^3 + (c + d*(a*x + b))*(2*Log[x] + c + d*(a*x + b))*Log[x]), 
  F[x], x]
```

Then, the resulting expression includes a symbolic integral as following

> ```
> F[x] -> 
>     C[1] + 
>       Integrate[a/(Log[K[1]]*(c + b*d + a*d*K[1] + Log[K[1]])^2), {K[1], 1, x}]
> ```

I also note that the *help* shows an example containing symbolic integral

```
DSolve[y'[x] == f[x], y[x], x]
```

However, it is easily to understand because $f(x)$ is unknown itself in the ODE.

My problems are:

1. In this case, `DSolve` returns a result, can I infer that my ODE has an *analytical solution*, even including some special function, which can be written in a closed form anyhow? That's why I am trying to solve it by `DSolve`.
2. How can I understand the symbolic integral in the result of my ODE properly? In other word, is there any approach to
   transform the expression into a form as an expression of *indefinite integral*?

Comment: You should understand it  as a sign that Mma does not know this integral. You might think about a numeric solution.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch, thanks, so you meant the closed form solution to my ODE does not exist.  However, `DSolve` returns the equation unchanged if it can not find the *closed form* solution usually. Why it transform the ODE into a symbolic integral?

Comment: I think you can interpret your result as _Mathematica_ saying your problem can be attacked better as an integration than as a differential equation.